# How can I show the three statuses of GitHub Actions jobs?

Tags: github-actions

In GitHub Actions we have three jobs. They all run independently of each other in the same workflow. As the last job I want to report in a Slack message the status of the three jobs if any of them have failed but I cannot seem to find a clear example of how to report the status of each.

What I currently have:

```yaml
report-failure:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  if: ${{ failure() }}
  needs: [test1, test2, test3]
  steps:
    - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.23.0
      env:
        SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
      with:
        channel-id: ${{ secrets.CHANNEL_ID }}
        slack-message: "Tests Have Failed.\nTEST 1: ${{ test1.result }}\nTest 2: ${{ test2.result }}\nTest 3: ${{ test3.result }}"
```

Since this is going to a public channel I am hesitant to just try it and see.  Wondering if anyone has experience with reporting like this from GitHub Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since this is going to a public channel I am hesitant to just try it and see

It means that, as long as you are testing, you can use [another notification medium](https://Since%20this%20is%20going%20to%20a%20public%20channel%20I%20am%20hesitant%20to%20just%20try%20it%20and%20see) (SMS, email, ...).
Or even just print the status.

Once you have the right status report, you can then add the Slack message.

One possible avenue would be to get the status of the 3 jobs through a fourth one (which will wait for the first three to complete).

```yaml
name: Example Workflow

on: [push]

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run job1
        run: echo "Job 1 complete"

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run job2
        run: echo "Job 2 complete"

  job3:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run job3
        run: echo "Job 3 complete"

  report:
    needs: [job1, job2, job3] # Ensure this job runs after the other three jobs
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get job statuses
        id: get_status
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          statuses=""
          for job in job1 job2 job3; do
            status=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
              https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/actions/runs/$GITHUB_RUN_ID/jobs \
              | jq -r --arg job_name "$job" '.jobs[] | select(.name==$job_name) | .conclusion')
            statuses="$statuses $job:$status"
          done
          echo "::set-output name=statuses::$statuses"
      - name: Display job statuses
        run: echo "Job Statuses: ${{ steps.get_status.outputs.statuses }}"
```